# Looking for a large pull-down hinge mechanism

Tags: shelving, metal, hinges, skylight

I have a large skylight, and currently have a shelf installed in it for indoor seed-starting. I would like to turn it into a pull-down shelf. I have found a clever design for hinges that might work, but none of the products I've seen are large enough for my use case.

1. Does anyone know of a product like this one that is larger - preferably with a 2-foot extension, rather than 9inches? My intention would be to use it upside-down, and push the shelf up into the skylight. [amazon product link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JFF39R3)

[image: hinges and coffee table usage]

2. I could probably buy the hydraulic pistons separately, but I don't have access to metal fabrication tools. Do you have any other ideas for how a DIYer could build these kind of hinges themselves with standard tools?
3. Do you have an idea for a different design that could also work?

Answer (score 2):

Cables, Pulleys, and Counterweights would probably be the easiest and most effective way to DIY a shelf to be raised into/lowered from a skylight without extensive fabrication abilities.